# Indenting bullets

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

It is not bad enough that I am so new to programming; This week I have done more Google searching and less Google finding than I have ever before.

Delphi v7

I have figured out how to create bullets in my richedit control. What I can't find out is how to indent them when the user creates them.

Any ideas?

Comment: What would be helpful would be to supply some code to show us what you currently have

Answer (score 11):

Set the `TRichEdit.Paragraph.FirstIndent`. The bullets will be indented by the additional amount of `FirstIndent`. (You use `FirstIndent` because a bullet item is the first line of a new paragraph.)

```
RichEdit1.Paragraph.FirstIndent := RichEdit1.Paragraph.FirstIndent + 10;
```

Here's a quick demo based on the RichEdit demo that's shipped with Delphi for years. I simply added two new `TToolButtons` to the `ToolBar` (the two right-most buttons, named `tbLessIndent` and `tbMoreIndent` respectively, with glyphs from the GlyFx images supplied with Delphi), and added the following event handlers to the existing form as the `ToolButton.OnClick` events:

```
procedure TMainForm.tbLessIndentClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Editor.Paragraph.FirstIndent := Editor.Paragraph.FirstIndent - 10;
  tbLessIndent.Enabled := Editor.Paragraph.FirstIndent > 9;
end;

procedure TMainForm.tbMoreIndentClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Editor.Paragraph.FirstIndent := Editor.Paragraph.FirstIndent + 10;
  tbLessIndent.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Here's a sample new document with a few items added:

[image: RichEdit bullet image snapshot]

For more info, see the documentation on [Numbering](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TParaAttributes.Numbering) and [FirstIndent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TParaAttributes.FirstIndent) (XE2 docs, but they're about the same)

Comment: Hello Ken, your sample project is amazing. Can I have a link to download it?

Comment: @TommySayugo: That demo above is directly from Delphi's own sample code (at least up until the last few versions). I have it still in Delphi 2007 (the easliest version I have installed now) in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\RichEdit